# Role of the factor $\frac{1}{|G|}$ in the definition of this positive-definite hermitian form

Tags: representation-theory

Theorem: If $G$ is a finite group and $\rho: G \to GL(V)$ is a representation of $G$ on a hermitian space $V$, then there exists a $G$-invariant, positive-definite hermitian form  $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ on $V$.

The proof of this theorem consists of defining the form

$$\langle v,w \rangle=\frac{1}{|G|} \displaystyle\sum_{g \in G}\{\rho_g(v),\rho_g(w)\},$$

where $\{\cdot,\cdot\}$ is a positive-definite hermitian form on $V$, then showing that it is a positive-definite hermitian form that is $G$-invariant.

I understand that the factor $\frac{1}{|G|}$ essentially just averages out the sum over the size of the group.  But, and this may well be obvious to most, is the factor of $\frac{1}{|G|}$ necessary, or is it more of a formality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly from the perspective of the invariance of $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$, you're right that dividing by the order of $G$ is unnecessary.

However, dividing by $|G|$ has one very nice effect

> **Proposition**:  Iterating this construction doesn't give anything new.  That is, if $\{ \cdot, \cdot \}$ was originally $G$-invariant, then $\{ \cdot, \cdot \} = \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$.

Comment: Very nice.  Thanks for the answer.